# Instantiating an IFormFile from a physical file

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have a physical file and I want to pass it to my controller method that requires an `IFormFile` type (for unit testing).

I can't find any classes that instantiate the `IFormFile` interface which means I can't create one.

How can I convert my physical file into an `IFormFile`?

Comment: There is one here https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/d035b7c533eecedb9a312ba0a383a3a6967c0c88/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Features/FormFile.cs but it is in the Internal namespace so you should not really use it. If this is for unit testing you can mock the interface or implement your own class used for testing purposes.

Answer (score 28):

You can instantiate a [FormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfile.-ctor). That implements `IFormFile`.

Example in .Net Core 3.1 (assume 'file' is physical path & file):

```
using var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file).ToArray());
var formFile = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, "streamFile", file.Split(@"\").Last());
```

Comment: Should we use classes that have internal namespaces?

Comment: Looks like FormFile was internal in .Net Core 2, and is now public in .Net Core 3+.

Answer (score 14):

Let's assume you have a controller method that accepts `IFormInfo`

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file) {

    FileDetails fileDetails = null;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream())) {
        var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue parsedContentDisposition = null;
        if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(file.ContentDisposition, out parsedContentDisposition)) {
            fileDetails = new FileDetails {
                Filename = parsedContentDisposition.FileName,
                Content = fileContent
            };
        }
    }

    return Task.FromResult((IActionResult)fileDetails);

}
```

Using a mocking framework like Moq. You can use a physical file to mock the `IFormFile`

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Controller_Should_Upload_FormFile() {
    // Arrange.
    var fileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
    var physicalFile = new FileInfo("filePath");
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
    writer.Write(physicalFile.OpenRead());
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    var fileName = physicalFile.Name;
    //Setup mock file using info from physical file
    fileMock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(fileName);
    fileMock.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(ms.Length);
    fileMock.Setup(_ => _.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
    fileMock.Setup(_ => _.ContentDisposition).Returns(string.Format("inline; filename={0}", fileName));
    //...setup other members as needed.

    var sut = new MyController();
    var file = fileMock.Object;

    // Act.
    var result = await sut.Upload(file);

    //Assert.
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(IActionResult));
}
```

The arranging of the mock can be even extracted into an extension method for reuse.

```
public static IFormFile AsMockIFormFile(this FileInfo physicalFile) {
    var fileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
    writer.Write(physicalFile.OpenRead());
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    var fileName = physicalFile.Name;
    //Setup mock file using info from physical file
    fileMock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(fileName);
    fileMock.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(ms.Length);
    fileMock.Setup(m => m.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
    fileMock.Setup(m => m.ContentDisposition).Returns(string.Format("inline; filename={0}", fileName));
    //...setup other members (code removed for brevity)


    return fileMock.Object;
}
```

and used like

```
var physicalFile = new FileInfo("filePath");
IFormFile formFile = physicalFile.AsMockIFormFile();
```

Comment: This looks okay but if you try to serialize fileMock.Object you get exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I tried Nkosi's answer (using .NET Core 3.1) but it would just return "System.IO.FileStream" as the file contents! Possibly because it's writing the FileStream object from physicalFile.OpenRead() to the output stream, as opposed to the actual contents of the stream. This modified version worked for me:

```
    public static IFormFile AsMockIFormFile(this FileInfo physicalFile)
    {
        var fileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
        using (FileStream fs = physicalFile.OpenRead())
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);

            while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(temp.GetString(b));
            }
        }
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        var fileName = physicalFile.Name;
        //Setup mock file using info from physical file
        fileMock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(fileName);
        fileMock.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(ms.Length);
        fileMock.Setup(m => m.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
        fileMock.Setup(m => m.ContentDisposition).Returns(string.Format("inline; filename={0}", fileName));
        //...setup other members as needed

        return fileMock.Object;
    }
```

Comment: Also note that in some circumstances, e.g. when using the DocumentFormat.OpenXml package to process files, I also had to add the following line: `physicalFile.IsReadOnly = true;`

Answer (score -1):

To convert a file path to IFormFile in C#, you can create a new instance of the FormFile class, passing in the file stream and the necessary file information. Here's an example:

```
string filePath = "path/to/your/file.ext";
string fileName = "file.ext";
string contentType = "application/octet-stream"; // or get the content type from the file itself

using(var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, fileName)
    {
        Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
        ContentType = contentType
    };

    // use the file as needed
}
```