# Good way to get images from the file system and send them using HttpClient to an API in C#

Tags: c#, http

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1. How can I get images from the file system and send them as IFormFile to an external API. The external API was built by me, I have total control over the code.

```
//here I grab the images from the file system.
List<String> images= System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\www\proj\wwwroot\fotos_produtos\" + produto.DirFotos).Select(Path.GetFullPath).ToList();

product.Image1 = /// Image1 is a IFormFile, how can I convert the File system image to Iform File

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:51265/api/produtos", product);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instantiating an IFormFile from a physical file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628743/instantiating-an-iformfile-from-a-physical-file)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I didn't like any of the answers. It seems they all tried random stuff!

Comment: You didn't "like" the answers, or they didn't work? If it's the latter, I'd be surprised, since [this answer specifically says they used ASP.NET Core 3.1, same as you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60185349/215552). If it's the former, well, suck it up. :) Not all solutions are wrapped up with a nice bow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IFormFile represents a file sent with the HttpRequest.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-3.1) That is, it is used on the server receiving the files. In your case, you should use `MultipartFormDataContent` and `ByteArrayContent`.

```
        var file = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync("your path");

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(file, 0, file.Length), "Image1", "image1.jpg");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("your url", form);
```

This way, `Image1` can be used as `IFormFile` on your server.

Comment: How should be my controller?I have the Product class as the parameter for the controller and I am getting null for all properties.

Comment: I was doing wrong, I was using PostJsonAsync instead of PostAsync.

Comment: Does it work, then? Do feel free to include your Controller code in the OP if it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, that's much more like what I wanted!